# How to implement a Basic Embedded Python block in GNU Radio flowgraph?

Tags: python, gnuradio, preamble, space-communications

I am trying to create a GNU Radio flowgraph for identifying a predefined preamble in satellite telemetry packets. For instance, the preamble can be "SAT_SAYS_HI". After identifying this sequence of bytes, the entire packet including "SAT_SAYS_HI" is written to a buffer of size equal to the packet size (256 bytes in this case).

Initially, this was being done by a Python script that was passing the packet to GNU Radio, but I require to embed the script in the flowgraph. I was able to successfully do this and print the packet to the terminal, but this was while using a sync block and passing dummy output to a sink. For practical purposes I cannot do this and need to pass the packet to the next block for processing.

For this, I will have to use a basic type block instead of sync (as input size keeps varying, 8, 16, 32, etc. but output size is fixed at 256).

After digging around some more, I found that the `general_work()` function needs to be overloaded in the class, however I am unable to find any documentation/video tutorials on how to go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

**TL;DR: How to successfully implement a basic type embedded python block in GNU radio flowgraph, with unequal number of samples in the input and output?**

Comment: you have an indentation error. That's a Python programming problem, not a signal processing issue! This might be better of on Stackoverflow.com, but just as here, it's impossible to help you if you don't paste the full Python code of your block, as well as state detailed version information.

Comment: Generally, what you describe very much sounds like an embedded python block is a bit too "ad hoc". Just make an OOT, and make a python block in there.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have edited out the Python part, as that wasn't relevant honestly. My main issue is how to use a basic embedded block in Python.
As for OOT, will that solve the issue I have? Of requiring to pass unequal input and output  sample sizes?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I had a look at the process of OOT module creation, there I still require to specify basic or sync block type, and I need basic but there's no documentation or resources on how to successfully implement a basic block in the first place, which is where I'm stuck. If I can make it work in OOT I'll also be able to make it work as an embedded Python block.